# Twilio - Sending SMS to a number once an SMS is received (Python)

Tags: python, sms, twilio

New to Twilio, have followed the [SMS Python Quickstart guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python) successfully, and have combined two bits together, but now have some redundant code that I can't seem to get rid of without getting errors.

I have Python code that takes in coordinates from a text message, converts this into a Google Maps link, and sends that link to a different phone number.

However, currently it is also sending this reply to the original sender phone number, as that is what the original guide has you set up.

I only want it to send the message to the specified number, not reply to the original sender.

run.py:

```
# /usr/bin/env python
# Download the twilio-python library from twilio.com/docs/libraries/python
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import Client

senderNo = '+442030954971'
receiverNo = '+447496070859'

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
account_sid = 'AC2b3b4c13ad0caa0da9f31717d7572141'
auth_token = 'd9d2cf9605bafe0b1a209c786b181653'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms_reply():

    messages = client.messages.list()

    print("Message received: " + messages[0].body)

    coord = messages[0].body

    lat,lon = coord.split(":")

    mapURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + lat + "," + lon

    print("Sending message")

    message = client.messages.create(
        body=mapURL,
        from_=senderNo,
        to=receiverNo
    )

    """Respond to incoming messages with a friendly SMS."""
    # Start our response
    resp = MessagingResponse()

    # Add a message
    resp.message(mapURL)

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Whenever I take out the lines I think are to do with the replying message to sender, it seems to break some of the other lines that I still need.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have 3 numbers sender, receiver and final_destination.  So you need to define two messages

1. message_received : from receiver, to sender
2. message_map : from receiver, to final_destination

Each with its own Messagingresponce object